# Неправильно отображается формат ячейки (количество часов и минут)

Tags: excel, excel-формулы

Мне нужно отобразить время превышающее 24 часа, я пишу в формате ячейки в поле Тип **[ч]:мм;@** и получаю ответ не 25 часов, а 241:00 кто сталкивался с подобным помогите пожалуйста решить проблему.

Ячейки выглядят следующим образом:

в 1-й ячейке дата с форматом (дата), во второй время (с форматом время) в 3 формула

```
=СЦЕПИТЬ(С1; D1) - СЦЕПИТЬ(A1;B1)
```

До 24 считает как нужно, а вот если выше 24 уже 241 и т.д
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте `[чч]:мм`

Comment: @Spatz Пробовал аналогичный эффект.

Comment: А что в ячейке-то? Если отформатировать как "дата-время", то, наверное, будет что-то вроде "09.01.1900 01:00"? То есть, те самые 25 часов + 9 суток?

Comment: @JohnSUN Добавил описание и скрин, если добавить дата и время тогда будет 10.01.00 1:00

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Дата* - целое число (количество суток), *время* - доля единицы (часть суток).

При сцепке двух значений (числа, тексты - не важно) в результате получим текст. Но так как дата и время - это числовые значения, то и работать с ними следует как с числами.

```
=C1+D1-(A1+B1)
```

Формат ячейки `[hh]:mm`

---

Почему у автора такой результат?

Задаем ячейкам формат *Общий*:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В ячейках видим реальные значения (десятичные числа), "не испорченные" форматом ячейки.

```
 =СЦЕПИТЬ(C1;D1)-СЦЕПИТЬ(A1;B1)

="443850,826388888888889"-"443840,708333333333333"
```

`СЦЕПИТЬ` - текстовая функция, результат каждой сцепки - текст, не число. При арифметических действиях над текстовыми записями числовых значений они (значения) преобразуются в числа. Результат: `10,1180555549799` = 10 суток (240:00) и какое-то время (2:50) = `242:50`

Comment: Большое спасибо за обьяснение и развёрнутый ответ